# Problems when simultaneously launching two programs with Bash

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi

I am trying to make a script on my **Raspberry Pi** that will launch **Omxplayer** (with a music file) and **claws-mail**, but I keep running into the same problems: Omxplayer can't find the file and claws-mail launches without my settings and gives an error about not finding a file in `./root` (my Pi is not available right now, so I can't give the exact error, but if it is needed I will post it). Here is what I have tried:

```
omxplayer ./Music/FileName.mp3 -p & claws-mail
sudo omxplayer ./Music/FileName.mp3 -p & claws-mail
omxplayer /home/pi/Music/FileName.mp3 -p & claws-mail
sudo omxplayer /home/pi/Music/FileName.mp3 -p & claws-mail
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error printouts and logs would be helpful.

If I understand you correctly, you want to play a sound and start claws-mail as the sound plays.

First of all, break this out to separate lines.

omxplayer can't find the file. This is probably due to you standing in the wrong directory, or executing this script from the wrong directory. Try using the complete absolute path, for example:

```
omxplayer -p /home/jason/Music/FileName.mp3 &
```

The & makes this a background job.

`claws-mail` can't find a file in root, you say. I rather guess that it hasn't got read access to a file in root's home directory. This is probably due to an erroneously configured claws-mail - it shouldn't have to access stuff there. Anyhow - to fix this, you should probably run

```
claws-mail
```

This will start claws-mail *as root*. This may or may not be what you want. You should probably reconfigure claws-mail so that it starts as your user, keeping the configurations in your home directory rather than root's.

Your complete script will look something like

```
#!/bin/bash

omxplayer -p /home/jason/Music/FileName.mp3 &
claws-mail
```

Comment: Thanks! The music is working fine now (the directory was wrong), but `sudo claws-mail` still launches it without my settings and gives the error. I also can't find any way to change it to my user. Any more ideas? The error is `/root/.claws-mail/clawsrc: fopen: No such file or directory.`

Comment: Try `claws-mail` without sudo - what happens then?

Comment: Yep. Running it in the terminal does not give the error and launches it correctly though.

Comment: How do you start the script?

Comment: sudo bash Script.sh, although I think I saw what you were suggesting, so removed sudo. Much to my delight, it worked! Thank you, thank you, thank you!